# Swift Generic Type in Function + Higher Order Function

Tags: swift, generics, higher-order-functions

let say I have a generic method to do some conversion that takes an Input and an Output, part of the process flows required a block (which takes the generic I and O too) to process it.

```
func run<I : Codable, O : Codable>(_ inputType: I, _ outputType: O, _ converter : (_ input: I)-> O) throws -> Void
{ 
    // do something to input I

    let output : O = converter(input)

    // do something else to output O
}
```

The problem is, I am unable to call this method like example:

```
run(InputObj, OutputObj) { (input) -> Codable in
        var outputObj = OutputObj( ... )
        // do something here
        return outputObj
}
```

and it show an error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(*) -> Codable' to
>   expected argument type '(*) -> _'

I have tried to change the block's return type "Codable" to "OutputObj" too.

Appreciate if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make this a method on a class. The problem in the simplified code in your question is that the closure is explicitly typed to return `Codable` but in the code in your answer it typed to return `OutputObj`.

If you remove the explicit return type for the closure in your example — and rely on the types being inferred from the `input` and `output` arguments — the code works without further modifications.

```
try run(inputObj, outputObj) { input in
    // do something and return an output object
}
```

---

Further, a few suggestions for Swift style improvements:

- It's redundant to return `Void` so you can remove that from the `run` function declaration.
- Swift usually tries to describe/name its generic parameters. For example, `Optional<Wrapped>`, `Array<Element>`, and `Dictionary<Key, Value>`. In your case `Input` and `Output` would be more descriptive than `I` and `O`.
- Swift usually doesn't use the `Type` suffix in type or variable names and the arguments that you pass to this function aren't types, they're values/instances. In this case `input` and `output` would be more idiomatic names for the two arguments.
- If it's clear from the argument types which one is the input and which one is the output then unlabeled arguments matches the Swift naming guidelines. Otherwise, the call site is clearer with labeled arguments (without the `_` before the argument names).

With these changes the `run` function declaration would look something like this:

```
func run<Input: Codable, Output: Codable>(input: Input, output: Output, converter: (Input) -> Output) throws
```

Answer (score 0):

OK!

I have found a way to fix this.
I  create a class for function "run"

```
class Converter<I : Codable, O : Codable> {
    func run(_ converter : (_ input: I)-> O) throws -> Void
}
```

then call by

```
let converter : Converter = Converter<InputObj, OutputObj>()
run() { (input) -> OutputObj in
    var outputObj = OutputObj( ... )
    // do something here
    return outputObj
}
```

any everything works perfectly now!